# Radius of convergence for $\sum\limits_{}^\ c_nx^{an+b}$ is $\sqrt[a]{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{}^\ c_nx^{n}$.

Show that $\sqrt[a]{R}$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{}^\ c_nx^{an+b}$. $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b \in \mathbb{N_0}$. What's with $R=\infty$?

---

Another task was to find $R$ for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+2}}{n4^n}$. I solved it with the ratio test. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^{2(n+1)+2}}{(n+1)4^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{n4^{n}}{x^{2n+2}}\right|=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{nx^{2}}{(n+1)4}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^{2}}{4+\frac 4n}\right|$

$\left|\frac{x^{2}}{4}\right|<1=\left|x\right|^{2}<4=\left|x\right|<2$
.

If you do this for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n+2}}{n4^n}$, the solution will be $\left|x\right|^{3}<4$. For $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4n+2}}{n4^n}$ it's $\left|x\right|^{4}<4$ and so on, the $2$ doesn't really do anything. That's probably relevant for the statement that I want to prove but I don't really know how to generalize this for $c_n$.

---

We also had this formula some time ago but I've never actually used it, the ratio test always seemed easier.
$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt[n]{\left|c_n\right|})}$ for $\sum\limits_{}^\ c_nx^{n}$. I don't even know how to find $R$ with this for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+2}}{n4^n}$, I have no idea how to find the $\limsup$ of a root, maybe that's just my problem. I can rewrite $\sum\limits_{}^\ c_nx^{an+b}$ as $\sum\limits_{}^\ c_nx^{an+b-n}x^n$, that could maybe be the first step of a proof.

Do I have to use the formula for the proof or is it also possible to do it with the ratio test? Our professor probably wants us to do it with the formula but I would like to see both if both are possible.

Comment: Use the ratio test (or the root test if you prefer) to prove the formula, then use that. You saw how involved the ratio test without the formula got, and that's beauty of proving this formula generally. You'll never have to do that tedious computation again if you can do the simpler one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write
$\sum\limits_{}^\ c_nx^{an+b}
=x^b\sum\limits_{}^\ c_n(x^{a})^n
$.

This converges for
$|x^a| < R
$,
so
$|x| < R^{1/a}$.